# eth_call, testing multiple transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

want to test multiple transactions which are changing state and are dependent of each other. Is that possible using geth?

```
Example:
(1) First transaction will send 1 eth to account a
(2) Second transaction will send 1 eth from account a to account b
```

Now the second transaction will fail, if they're split and tested by eth_call. Need to "group" them so state produced by transaction (1) will be used by transaction (2)

Comment: Hey could you please share your solution if you found a way to simulate multiple transactions via eth_call? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible as far as I know but the go-ethereum team is looking into this possibility. See [Issue #24089](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/24089)